# Scrape 2 different format tables from webpage - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

So I'm aiming to scrape 2 tables (in different formats) from a website - [FSC Public Search](https://info.fsc.org/details.php?id=a0240000005sQjGAAU&type=certificate) after iterating this over a list of license codes. My issue is that because the two tables I want, Product Data and Certificate Data are in 2 different formats, so I have to scrape them separately. Eg the Product data is in the normal `"tr"` format on the webpage and the Certificate Data is in `"div"` form.

From a previous question I asked, I have almost resolved my issue and I can retrieve the Certificate data ("div" form) completely fine over a range of license codes. However I can't get the Product Data table to output as I wish. Instead of showing the product data for the 5 license codes, it shows me 5 copies of the first license code. I've tried putting this scraping in the defined function get_data_by_code but I still couldn't get it in the format I would like, which is just a table in a CSV file.

Basically I'm not sure where to include this scraping in my function/script so any input would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv("MS_License_Codes.csv")
codes = df["License Code"]
data = [
        ('code', code),
        ('submit', 'Search'),
        ]
response = requests.post('https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php', data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')



def get_data_by_code(code):
    data = [
        ('code', code),
        ('submit', 'Search'),
    ]

    response = requests.post('https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php', data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')


 #scraping the certificate data

    status = soup.find_all("label", string="Status")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    first_issue_date = soup.find_all("label", string="First Issue Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    last_issue_date = soup.find_all("label", string="Last Issue Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    expiry_date = soup.find_all("label", string="Expiry Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    standard = soup.find_all("label", string="Standard")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text


    return [code, status, first_issue_date, last_issue_date, expiry_date, standard]

# Just insert here output filename and codes to parse...
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'Certificate_Data.csv'

df3 = pd.DataFrame()

with open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for code in codes:
        print('Getting code# {}'.format(code))
        writer.writerow((get_data_by_code(code)))

##attempting to scrape the product data

        table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
        df1, = pd.read_html(str(table))
        df3 = df3.append(df1) 

df3.to_csv('Product_Data.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

**EDIT**

So using this code below, I get 5 copies of the last license code's Product Data.. marginally closer but I still don't see why this is the case

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for code in codes:
    print('Getting code# {}'.format(code))
    response = requests.post('https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php', data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
    df1, = pd.read_html(str(table))
    df3 = df3.append(df1)        

df3.to_csv('Product_Data.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

**EDIT 2**

The sample codes I have been using:

```
codes = ['FSC-C001777', 'FSC-C124838' ,'FSC-C068163','FSC-C101537','FSC-C005776']
```

**Format Edit**

This is the correct tabular format however as you can see, it is the information from the first license code repeated 5 times as opposed to the unique data.

[image: Product Data]

This is the format & information I want, everything working fine here:
[image: Certificate Data]

Comment: @MartinEvans I added some below, in EDIT 2.

Comment: What is your expected output for the codes you have given? Could you add what the CSV file should look like (in text format) ?

Comment: @MartinEvans I wasn't sure what you meant by text format so I added screenshots of my current outputs, as they are in the correct format, just one of them has the wrong information.

Comment: Thank you. The raw text is preferred rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `codes` you have provided, this simplified approach should suffice. It simply extracts the necessary information directly from BeautifulSoup without needing to use Pandas to try and extract it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

fieldnames_cert = ['Code', 'Status', 'First Issue Date', 'Last Issue Date', 'Expiry Date', 'Standard']
fieldnames_prod = ['Code', 'Product Type', 'Trade Name', 'Species', 'Primary Activity', 'Secondary Activity', 'Main Output Category']

codes = ['FSC-C001777', 'FSC-C124838', 'FSC-C068163', 'FSC-C101537', 'FSC-C005776']

with open('Certificate_Data.csv', 'wb') as f_output_cert, \
     open('Product_Data.csv', 'wb') as f_output_prod:

    csv_output_cert = csv.writer(f_output_cert)
    csv_output_cert.writerow(fieldnames_cert)

    csv_output_prod = csv.writer(f_output_prod)
    csv_output_prod.writerow(fieldnames_prod)

    for code in codes:
        print('Getting code# {}'.format(code))
        response = requests.post('https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php', data={'code' : code, 'submit' : 'Search'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

        # Extract the certificate data
        div_cert = soup.find('div', class_='certificatecl')
        csv_output_cert.writerow([code] + [div.text for div in div_cert.find_all('div')])

        # Extract the product data
        table = soup.find('h2', id='products').find_next_sibling('table')

        for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            row = [td.get_text(strip=True).encode('utf-8') for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            csv_output_prod.writerow([code] + row)
```

This would produce `Certificate_Data.csv` containing:

```
Code,Status,First Issue Date,Last Issue Date,Expiry Date,Standard
FSC-C001777,Valid,2009-04-01,2018-02-16,2019-04-01,FSC-STD-40-004 V3-0
FSC-C124838,Valid,2015-03-23,2015-03-23,2020-03-22,FSC-STD-40-004 V3-0
FSC-C068163,Valid,2010-03-01,2017-08-23,2022-08-22,FSC-STD-40-003 V2-1;FSC-STD-40-004 V3-0
FSC-C101537,Valid,2010-10-01,2013-11-28,2018-11-27,FSC-STD-40-003 V2-1;FSC-STD-40-004 V3-0
FSC-C005776,Valid,2007-07-17,2017-07-17,2022-07-16,FSC-STD-40-004 V3-0
```

And produce `Product_Data.csv` containing:

```
Code,Product Type,Trade Name,Species,Primary Activity,Secondary Activity,Main Output Category
FSC-C001777,W12 Indoor furnitureW12.4 Beds,,,Secondary Processor,Secondary Processor,FSC Mix
FSC-C124838,"W18 Other manufactured wood productsW18.4 Tools, tool bodies and handles",, Abies spp; Betula spp.; Fagus sylvatica L.; Hevea brasiliensis; Paulownia tomentosa (Thunb. ex Murr) Steud; Picea spp.; Populus spp.; Quercus spp; Schima wallichii (DC.) Korth.; Swietenia macrophylla; Tilia spp.; Ulmus spp.,brokers/traders with physical posession,,FSC Mix;FSC 100%;FSC Recycled
FSC-C068163,P2 Paper,,,brokers/traders with physical posession,Distributor/Wholesaler,FSC Mix;FSC 100%;FSC Recycled
FSC-C068163,P3 Paperboard,,,brokers/traders with physical posession,Distributor/Wholesaler,FSC Mix;FSC 100%;FSC Recycled
FSC-C101537,P8 Printed materials,,,Printing and related service,Secondary Processor,FSC Mix;FSC 100%;FSC Recycled
FSC-C101537,P7 Stationery of paper,,,Printing and related service,Secondary Processor,FSC Mix;FSC 100%;FSC Recycled
FSC-C005776,W12 Indoor furnitureW12.10 Cupboards and chests,"Outros produtos, (baú, quadro espelho, etc.)", Eucalyptus spp; Pinus spp.,Secondary Processor,,FSC Mix
FSC-C005776,W12 Indoor furnitureW12.7 Office furniture,"Produtos para escritório (escrivaninha, mesa, gaveteiros, etc.)", Eucalyptus spp; Pinus elliottii,Secondary Processor,,FSC Mix
FSC-C005776,W12 Indoor furnitureW12.12 Parts of furniture,"Partes de movéis, (peças de reposição)", Eucalyptus spp; Pinus taeda,Secondary Processor,,FSC Mix
FSC-C005776,W12 Indoor furnitureW12.4 Beds,Camas, Eucalyptus spp; Pinus taeda,Secondary Processor,,FSC Mix
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Martin! However I think I may have explained my issue poorly. The table you outlined above in your answer is the one that I have already extracted successfully. It is the other table (see my "product data" image in the edit) which has data such as indoor furniture, beds etc in the text fields. It is this table that I am unable to extract correctly when looping over my license codes.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't spotted you were creating two outputs per page. Pandas `read_html()` can sometimes be really useful, but when it fails, it is better to roll your own code to extract the information you need.

Comment: That's amazing thank you so much!! I hate to bug you but everything works perfectly until the last license code (for me at least, maybe because I have python 2.7) but I get this error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128). I tried adding .encode('utf-8').strip() after row however this resulted in an error. Is there another way to fix this issue?

Comment: You could add it inside the list comprehension. Also if you are using Python 2.x, you need to change to use `'wb'` as the write mode. I have updated the script.

Comment: I solved the issue myself with this sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')! Thank you again so much for your help and feedback, it's helped massively.